# Stop scraping of default metric in prometheus_client in python

Tags: python, prometheus

I am integrating prometheus to scrape custom metrics from my application. However I am receiving lots of unwanted metric which are enabled by default. Is there a way to disable these metric, so as to collect only the custom metrics I want.

reference for the prometheus client I am using - https://github.com/prometheus/client_python

Comment: Are you talking about `process_cpu_seconds_total` and such? Please add some examples.

Comment: yes. those metrics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, in my opinion those are useful metrics, you can remove them with `REGISTRY.unregister()`:

```py
from time import sleep
import prometheus_client as prom

prom.REGISTRY.unregister(prom.PROCESS_COLLECTOR)
prom.REGISTRY.unregister(prom.PLATFORM_COLLECTOR)
prom.REGISTRY.unregister(prom.GC_COLLECTOR)

g = prom.Gauge("test", "test")

prom.start_http_server(port=9999)

while True:
    sleep(1)
    g.inc(1)
```

`PROCESS_COLLECTOR`, `PLATFORM_COLLECTOR`, and `GC_COLLECTOR` are the sources of the default metrics (you can find them in the `__init__.py` of the package). The default registry (`prom.REGISTRY`, that is) collect metrics from them at the scrape time, so by using  `unregister()` you effectively make the registry to forget about those sources.

The above is for a case when you work with the default registry. There is another way, which is to instantiate your own registry and pass it everywhere:

```py
from time import sleep
import prometheus_client as prom

reg = prom.CollectorRegistry()
g = prom.Gauge("test", "test", registry=reg)

prom.start_http_server(port=9999, registry=reg)

while True:
    sleep(1)
    g.inc(1)
```

Testing both you will get something like this:

```
❯ curl localhost:9999/metrics
# HELP test test
# TYPE test gauge
test 3.0
```